# How to check data in select for one value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can`t make write script for my selection.

I have such table with some services:

```
+----------+-------------+------------+
| Serv_cod |  Start_Date |  End_Date  |
+----------+-------------+------------+
|       1  | 01/03/2015  | 01/03/2999 |
|       2  | 20/03/2015  | 20/03/2999 |
|       2  | 01/01/2012  | 18/03/2015 |
|       3  | 13/03/2015  | 13/03/2999 |
|       3  | 03/05/2011  | 12/02/2015 |
|       4  | 14/03/2009  | 27/03/2015 |
|       4  | 28/03/2015  | 28/03/2999 |
+----------+-------------+------------+
```

I need to select only that services that started not more than in 5 days after service with the same name ended. I`d like to get such result:

```
+----------+-------------+------------+
| Serv_cod |  Start_Date |  End_Date  |
+----------+-------------+------------+
|       2  | 20/03/2015  | 20/03/2999 |
|       2  | 01/01/2012  | 18/03/2015 |
|       4  | 14/03/2009  | 27/03/2015 |
|       4  | 28/03/2015  | 28/03/2999 |
+----------+-------------+------------+
```

I`ve tried to resolve it with such script:

```
select * from serv 
where serv_cod in ( 
select serv_cod from serv a
inner join serv b
on a.serv_cod=b.serv_code
where a.start_date between b.end_date - 5 and b.end_date  )
```

But I didn`t get result I want. 
Can anyone help? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: between dateadd(day,-5,b.end_date) and b.end_date

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the intervals are not overlapping, in SQL Server 2012+, you can use `lag()`:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             lag(end_date) over (partition by serv_code order by start_date) as prev_end_date
      from serv s
     ) s
where start_date <= dateadd(day, 5, prev_end_date) and
      start_date >= prev_end_date
```

Otherwise, you can alway use `exists`:

```
select s.*
from serv s
where exists (select 1
              from serv s2
              where s.start_date <= dateadd(day, 5, s2.end_date) and
                    s.start_date >= s2.end_date
             );
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon! Intervals may overlap. Unfortunately, I don't understand your second script.

Comment: @Andrii . . . I didn't understand it either until I fixed the column references.